# How to get url in php which pushed in history using pushState

Tags: php, pushstate

I changed the browser url using `historty.pushState();`

```
window.history.pushState('data', null, entityUrl);
```

Then I just want to grab that url in php function. I am using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` global variable but not getting the modified url.

Plz help
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

window.history.pushState will not send a request to the server, so you will never be able to have the url with php.

If you need it you may consider sending an ajax request to the server just to tell the url to it.